# Как ssh выбирает ключ для сервера?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, шифрование

Правильно ли я понимаю что ssh ключи закрытые хранятся все в одной файле ~/.ssh/id_rsa и там их может быть много?

Как именно тогда ssh понимаем по какому ключу к какому серверу подключится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, вы понимаете неправильно. В одном файле хранится ровно один приватный ключ. Если вы хотите использовать несколько разных пар ключей, используйте для них разные имена.

`ssh` перебирает несколько имён файлов. Среди них есть и `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Выдержка из `man ssh`:

> ```
> -i identity_file
>      Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for
>      public key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity
>      for protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
>      ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.
>      Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the
>      configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options
>      (and multiple identities specified in configuration files). ...
> ```

Создайте конфигурационный файл, чтобы для разных серверов использовать разные ключи. Обычно он лежит в `~/.ssh/config`. Читайте `man ssh_config`.

Comment: я должен еще раз поблагодарить Вас за точный и подробный ответ. Дело в том, что у меня тоже возникал подобный вопрос, я тоже его задавал, и я тоже его не решил. "Создайте конфигурационный файл, чтобы для разных серверов использовать разные ключи" - я эту магию подчинить себе не смог: примера не нашел, а самому написать слабО.

Comment: @S.H. , тогда имеет смысл задать вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, погуглил немного, нашел вроде довольно понятную статью https://freehost.com.ua/faq/articles/kak-nastroit-ssh-s-pomoschju--ssh-config/
Думаю, что в прошлый раз у меня просто не хватило терпения

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в `~/.ssh/id_rsa` находится твой приватный ключ. То есть, по нему ты можешь подключаться к другим пк. Например, у тебя в папке лежит `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` если ты его скопируешь и на другой машине в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` запишешь его, то с помощью команды `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ip` сможешь законнектиться без пароля.

То есть, в этом файле хранится лишь твой приватный ключ, с помощью которого ты общаешься с другими пк по `ssh`

Answer (score 1):

я хочу дополнить ответ, который уже есть.

Вообще говоря, в папке `%userprofile%/.ssh` может находиться несколько публичных и несколько приватных ключей.

Но обратите внимание. Для того, чтобы при соединении с сервером по ssh работала авторизация по ключам - на сервер должен быть скопирован Ваш публичный ключ.

я бы **предположил**, что во время сеанаса связи с сервером сервер говорит "у меян вот такой публичный ключ для этого пользователя есть, ну ка, глянь, у тебя есть правильная приватная часть?" - и тогда уже ваш компьютер заходит в `%userprofile%/.ssh`, находит там публичную часть ключа, по ней находит приватную и проверяет, что публичный ключ - правильный.

На этом мои сообращения по заданному вопросу заканчиваются :-)

А теперь - просто такой интересный факт: в некоторых случаях публичная часть ключа не нужна. Её можно сгененриовать из приватной части. Правда, опять так, как мне кажется (и пусть меня поправят, если я не прав) в разных случаях из одной и той же приватнйо части может быть сгенерирована, вообще говоря, *разная* публичная часть.

Вот первая попавшаяся [ссылка](https://muff.kiev.ua/content/ssh-vosstanovlenie-public-key-iz-private-key) на эту тему:

"При использовании ssh-авторизации по ключам, иногда бывает так что вследствии перезаписывания или удаления, теряется публичная часть ключа - id_dsa.pub (или id_rsa.pub соответственно). Однако, имея в наличии приватную часть ключа, можна восстановить публичную, используя всего одну команду.

DSA:

```
    # ssh-keygen -y -f id_dsa > id_dsa.pub
```

RSA:

```
    # ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```